# Does a constrained nonlinear program only have one KKT point?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am just wondering whether or not a constrained nonlinear program has only one KKT point?

Intuitively, I think this is wrong and the only thing we can conclude is that any KKT in such program is also a global minimum.

Comment: There are cases where it can have only one KKT point. But generally not.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The KKT conditions are a local check in the neighborhood of a single point.  There may be many other points satisfying the KKT conditions in other disjoint neighborhoods, and therefore one cannot make a claim about global optimality about one such point without potentially checking all others and placing some restrictions on the nonlinear program itself.

Comment: Additionally, even if the program is convex and differentiable, there may be many global optima, and thus multiple KKT points.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the very simple nonlinear program
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}}&\quad \sin(\pi x) \\
\text{s.t.} &\quad x^2-3x+2=0
\end{aligned}
$$
It has two feasible points $x=1$ and $x=2$, and both are optimal since they yield the same objective value. You are welcome to verify that both are indeed KKT points.